# How to remove a specific stroke in HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, stroke

I make several strokes in a HTML5 canvas.
To make animation with stroke, I clear the previous like this :

```
    // Notice : canvasWidth, canvasHeight, context are in a parent scope
    function echoLine( posLeftX, posLeftY, posRightX, posRightY) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(posLeftX, posLeftY);
        context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        context.bezierCurveTo(posLeftX, posLeftY, posRightX, posLeftY, posRightX, posRightY);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();
    }
```

My problem is when I want to do several animated lines, `context.clearRect()` will remove all and I did not find a other way to remove the specific stroke.

Is there a way to clear a specific stroke without workaround, or should I make context by stroke ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep an array of lines, and draw them all every time, then delete is a simple `splice` on the array, you just have to slightly change your draw function to clear then loop over the array that is where we do all drawings.

Here is an example.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d")
var lines = []

function draw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  lines.forEach((e, i) => {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(e.left.x, e.left.y);    
    context.fillText(i, e.left.x-7, e.left.y);
    context.bezierCurveTo(e.left.x, e.left.y, e.right.x, e.left.y, e.right.x, e.right.y);
    context.stroke();
  })
}

function animate() {
  lines.forEach((e) => { 
    if (e.right.y > 150 || e.right.y < 0) e.speed *= -1 
    e.right.y += e.speed      
  })
  draw()
}

document.getElementById('todelete').onkeyup = (event) => {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    lines.splice(event.srcElement.value, 1)
    event.srcElement.value = ""
  }
};

for (var i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
  lines.push({ 
    left:  { x:10,   y:130 - i*16 }, 
    right: { x:i*30, y:50 - i*6 }, 
    speed: 0.2 + Math.random() 
  })
}

setInterval(animate, 40)
```

```css
input {
  width: 160px
}
```

```html
<input id="todelete" type="number"  min="0" max="5" placeholder="enter number to delete" >
Press enter to submit.
<br>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=150></canvas>
```